# Python property vs method when no access to attribute is needed?

Tags: python, properties

I am reading "Python programming for the absolute beginner" and in there there is this piece of code:

```
@property
def mood(self):
    unhappiness = self.hunger + self.boredom
    if unhappiness < 5:
        m = "happy"
    elif 5 <= unhappiness <= 10:
        m = "okay"
    elif 11 <= unhappiness <= 15:
        m = "frustrated"
    else:
        m = "mad"
    return m
```

All it does is calculate on-the-fly and return the calculation. It doesn't provide access to a private attribute or any attribute of the class. Is this better as property rather than method?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Properties are not intended for providing access to a private attribute. Properties are intended to give you the option of making zero-argument methods accessible as if they were attributes, so that a given "attribute" can be implemented as either a calculation or an actual attribute, without changing the interface of the class.

As such, it's usually not really a question of "better", but rather a design decision with pros and cons that depend on the context.

In this case, whatever this object is supports `x.hunger`, `x.boredom` and `x.mood`. Why not `x.mood()`? You could, although that exposes permanently in the interface that it *is* a calculation and is not stored.

If a prior version of the class had a "real" `mood` attribute, and a required invariant of the object meant that any internal method updating `boredom` or `hunger` had to also carefully set `mood` to be consistent, then introducing the property would be an excellent refactor; the interface stays the same, but the invariant is now guaranteed to always hold, rather than having to be carefully maintained. A whole field of bugs are made impossible to occur.

On the other hand, if `mood` is expensive to calculate, or has side effects, then it likely would be much better as a normal method. Making it look like an attribute access means that client code programmers will likely *think* of it as an attribute access, which is cheap and non-destructive; this would be a rich source of bugs or performance problems.

Comment: Yes I did get to the same conclusion that it is design decision and mood() is better as it shows calculation. This way people know that it is not stored.

Comment: @h3dkandi Actually my conclusion (in this case) is that it is better *not* to expose that it's a calculation; abstract interfaces and encapsulating implementation details are the point of OO after all! But that just shows that this is a subjective decision with no "right" answer. :)

Comment: Well yes I can see your point. It might be better to be hidden.

Comment: "cheap and non-destructive" perfect

Answer (score 7):

It's just a matter of taste.

A property is used where an access is rather cheap, such as just querying a "private" attribute, or a simple calculation.

A method is used where a rather "complicated" process takes place and this process is the main thing.

People are used to using getter and setter methods, but the tendency is used for useing properties more and more.

Take, as an example, the `Serial` class of `pyserial`. It has - as a heritage - methods such as `getBaudRate()` and `setBaudRate()`, but recommends to use `baudrate` as a reading and writing property for querying and setting the baud rate.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think there is any real difference.

It just allows you to do `obj.mood` instead of `obj.mood()`

Answer (score 3):

It's essentially a preference. It allows you to type `object.property` rather than `object.property()`.

So when should you use which? You have to use context to decide. If the method you have returns a value based upon properties of the object, it saves you the time of creating a variable and setting it equal to some generator method (example: `property = object.generateProperty()`. Doesn't it make more sense to just skip this step, and make `generateProperty()` a property of its own?

This is the general concept as I understand it.

Comment: I agree. I would prefer the method and write the variable if the getter is expensive and you are using it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a very good reason to use this (which I just encountered). In your case, it may not seem like doing much. But imagine having two classes:

```
class Person(object):
    hunger = 3
    boredom = 5

    @property
    def mood(self):
        unhappiness = self.hunger + self.boredom
        if unhappiness < 5:
            m = "happy"
        elif 5 <= unhappiness <= 10:
            m = "okay"
        elif 11 <= unhappiness <= 15:
            m = "frustrated"
        else:
           m = "mad"
        return m

class Werewolf(object):
    mood = "mad"
```

In this case, "Werewolf's" are always "mad", but "Person's" are conditionally "mad".

Now, if you had a generic method where:

```
if time == "full moon"
    player = Werewolf
else:
    player = Person
```

then you can "safely" just say

```
mood_at_this_time = player.mood
```

without worrying about making a method call.

Comment: I do understand what you are trying to say but dunno if your example is good. I would implement Werewolf as a subclass of Person. The physical form dependent on the moon phase(human/wolf), as well as the mood as per your example. What I mean a werewolf is still a werewolf when in human form. I see it as a 'sick' person :). I see your example as class A and subclass B where A property is calculated and B property is 'constant'