# Why does the .text method in Selenium Python not have parentheses?

Tags: python

In Selenium Python, when I want to find the text of an element on the webpage, I use the ".text" method. The thing that confuses me though is that it has no parentheses. Could anyone explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding what are properties used for check out: [Python property vs method when no access to attribute is needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506612/python-property-vs-method-when-no-access-to-attribute-is-needed#:~:text=A%20property%20is%20used%20where,process%20is%20the%20main%20thing.)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `text` is a property, not a method. From [WebElement docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement)

```
@property
def text(self) -> str:
    """The text of the element."""
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
```

Comment: What are properties used for? Sorry if that's a dumb question.

Comment: @Penderdrill I suggest you go over the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score -1):

This is not really a selenium question, but a question of methods (functions) and properties (variables).

```py
class Hello:
    '''an example class '''
    
    # a variable
    space = 'b'

    def world():
        ''' a function '''
        return 'a'


x = Hello.space   # <--- no parenthesis needed
y = Hello.world() # <--- this is the function

print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Ohhh. So you're just printing out a variable that's inside of a class already?

Comment: `text` is a property, not class variable. Those are two different things.

Comment: @Guy   just illustrating how something does not need the parenthasis to be called...

Comment: @Penderdrill,  yes.  the answer is very simplistic, but highlights why one does not always need parenthesis.